# GAE Task Queue processing time in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, task-queue

In my jsp web application, when i processed a report it always cause DeadlineExceededException. So i moved the process into Task Queue of app engine.
But using task queue, it will not generate report and never shows any eeror message. Is task queue a proper solution for DeadlineExceededException or Task Queue have a time limit of 1 minute for processing.

My queue.xml is configured as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>default</name>
        <rate>5/s</rate>
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name>subscription-queue</name>
        <rate>5/s</rate>
    </queue>
    <queue>
        <name>excel-generator-queue</name>
        <rate>5/s</rate>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

Answer (score 1):

The task queue time-out limit is much greater than 1 minute. (It should be at least 10 minutes; you'll have to read the GAE docs to find out).

Also, check whether you are using push or pull queues and whether you are happy with your choice. I think that your config may be for the default queue type of push.

Have you placed any logging code in the code called by the enqueued tasks? This will allow you to find out whether the code is executing or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are two deadlines to consider - the deadline for individual App Engine API calls that you make, and the overall deadline for your task processing.

When you call an App Engine API, sometimes the call won't complete within about 5 seconds, and you will receive a DeadlineExceededException. You have the option of making the call again. Some APIs like Url Fetch and Lease Tasks allow you to specify the deadline. If you catch the exception, you will see which code timed out.

When using task queues, the overall deadline for your task processing is 10 minutes, unless you are using Backends - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/
(When not using task queues, the overall deadline is only 60 seconds.)

The question mentions "it will not generate report". When tasks are being executed, there is no web browser present to see progress reports or the final report. Add some logging to your report generation. Store the generated report in the data store, or email it.